# Setting a future date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick event is failing capturing a future date.  I keep receiving the custom error message stating, "the pending date has already passed."

This feature has worked in the past, and I could've sworn it worked at the end of 2018.  Not sure why it's failing now.

Button click event:

```
$('#markPendingSubmit').on('click', function(){
  var pendingDate = $('#reservationtime').val();
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();   
  if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
  }

  console.log(pendingDate); // <-- correct prints user selected date (which is 01/09/2019)

  if(mm<10) {
   mm='0'+mm
  }
  today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

  if(pendingDate <= today)
  {
    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    $('.message').text('The pending date you selected has already passed. Please select a future pending date.');
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    // complete process
  }   
});
```

The user is attempting to set the 'pendingDate' to 1/09/2019, which is then compared to the variable 'today', but is failing because it's reading 1/09/2019 as a date that has already passed, even though today's date is 12/18/2018.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: you should compare date object and not string

Comment: @Alays - So I need to convert 'pendingDate' to a date object, being that 'today' is a date object.  Is that correct?

Comment: `pendingDate = new Date('01/09/2019')`
and then `pendingDate<=today`

Comment: yes but your var today is then cast in string today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem:

```
if(new Date(pendingDate) <= new Date(today))
{
  $('#errorModal').modal('show');
  $('.message').text('The pending date you selected has already passed. Please select a future pending date.');
  return false;
}
```

Thus, both 'pendingDate' and 'today' are ensured to be Date objects, and therefore can be compared in an if/else statement.

Such a simple fix.

Comment: Note that this is risky, due to the differences in date parsing methods across browsers. See the answers to [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - thank you for the input.  I will take it into consideration.